# Asterisk console output 'no button pressed' on no DTMF input

Tags: asterisk

I've got an outbound survey program, here is an example of what the survey does from the dialplan.

```
same => n(xtn_age),Read(AGE,rbp_age,2)
    same => n,Set(CDR(age)=${AGE})
    same => n,Set(CURRENT_XTN=xtn_age)
    same => n,GotoIf($["${AGE}" >"0" & "${AGE}"<="99"]?xtn_sex:invalidopt)
```

When no DTMF input is received the console prints a single line (no datestamp or id):

```
no button pressed
```

No matter what level I set in logger.conf, I get this message. That's fine, but I'm doing thousands of outbound calls, which means thousands of lines saying 'no button pressed' on my console, which makes it really hard to see the input I'm most interested on.

Here's the relevant part of my logger.conf:

```
console => notice,warning,error,dtmf
```

Does anyone know how I can stop this logging to the console, so that I can concentrate on the stuff I'm interested in?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeing is based on the verbosity level in the console. I'd start with doing "core set verbose 1" and increment it until you get the details you want without the details you don't want.

Comment: thanks I just tested your suggestion, however my verbosity was set to 0 already. I set verbose and debug to zero, but I'm still getting the message.

Comment: Are you looking for the DTMF to be printed into the console in particular? If so. I would just use NoOp right after the Read. "same => n,NoOp(rbp_age: ${rbp_age})" I would also take the dtmf part out of the logger.conf for the console line.

Comment: I'll give that a go.